# What does $\mathbb P\{X\geq 1\}$ mean in probability theory?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

> Let $(\Omega ,F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $X$ a random variable.  I have a doubt on a definition.

- Does $\mathbb P\{X>1\}=0$
  means that $X(\omega )\leq 1$ for all $\omega \in \Omega $ ?
- Or it can have an $\omega \in \Omega $ s.t. $X(\omega )>1$ ?

---

For example, I know that in a measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B,m)$, we have for example for $f=\mathbb 1_\mathbb N$ that $$m\{x\mid f(x)=1\}=0,$$ but $f(1)=1$ anyway (i.e. that there exist very few but some $x$ s.t. $f(x)=1$).

---

Does for probability it's the same or to say that $$\mathbb P\{X\in A\}=0$$
tell us that there is no $\omega \in \Omega $ s.t. $X(\omega )\in A$ ?

Comment: Your title and your body refer to different probability.

Comment: There **can** be $\omega$ such that $X(\omega) >1$ but the set of $\omega$'s satisfying this is so small it's negligible (in other words, it's as if there are no $\omega$ satisfying $X(\omega) > 1$ because if the set is that small, it doesn't affect any computations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$P(X>1)=0$ implies that $P(X\le1)=1$ since
$$
P(X>1)=1-P(X\le1).
$$
It does not imply that $X(\omega)\le1$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$. It only says that the set of $\omega$'s such that $X(\omega)>1$ has measure equal to $0$ or, equivalently, the set of $\omega$'s such that $X(\omega)\le 1$ has measure equal to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb P$ is a measure on $Ω$. Hence, $\mathbb P(X>1)=0$ means that $$\mathbb P\left(\{ω: X(ω)\le1\}\right)=0$$ or in other words there may be $ω$'s such that $X(ω)\le 1$ but the set of all such $ω$'s has measure equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(X\geq 1)$ is $P(\{X\geq 1\})$ for short and in general $P(X\in A)$ is $P(\{X\in A\})$ for short.

The notation {$X\geq1$} for a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ really means the *event*
$$
\{X\geq 1\}:=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\geq 1\}.
$$
In general 
$$
\{X\in A\}:=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\in A\}
$$
for any Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$.